# Product URLs and Category URLs need to be IDENTICAL while migrating from Magento to Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, magento

We are migrating from Megento shopping site to WordPress using WooCommerce plugin. All the categories, products and images have been downloaded to WordPress Server from Megento site.

Here is the Megento site:
http://www.8dim.com

And here is our new WordPress site:
http://dev.unwaveringmedia.com/8dim/

We will be developing this new WordPress site for categories, products, after we develop then we will be pushing it to domain 8dim.com in order to replace it with old Megneto site.

We need the products & categories URLs identical for new WordPress site as it was before for Megento. Right now, they are not identical on our WordPress development site like:

MEGENTO URLS:

http://www.8dim.com/all-party-supplies.html 
http://www.8dim.com/all-party-supplies/holiday-parties.html 
http://www.8dim.com/all-party-supplies/holiday-parties/christmas.html 
http://www.8dim.com/14-snowman-serving-tray.html

DEVELOPMENT WORDPRESS URLS:
http://dev.unwaveringmedia.com/8dim/product-category/all-party-supplies/
http://dev.unwaveringmedia.com/8dim/product-category/all-party-supplies/holiday-parties/
http://dev.unwaveringmedia.com/8dim/product-category/all-party-supplies/holiday-parties/christmas/
http://dev.unwaveringmedia.com/8dim/product/14-snowman-serving-tray/

This site gets a lot of it's traffic from SEO rankings, so we need to make sure that we don't lose any of those rankings when we push the dev. site on 8Dim.com.

if you note the Megento site is rendering product with .html but the wp does not. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How to differentiate between `/all-party-supplies.html` and `/14-snowman-serving-tray.html` were first is supposed to go to categories page and 2nd to products page.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all of your URLs are modified following these rules:

1. Remove .html
2. Add 'product-category' for category pages
3. Add 'product' for specific product pages

What you would want is a mod_rewrite that will take care of this for you, something like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.+)/(.+)\.html$ /product-category/$1/$2/
RewriteRule ^/(.+)\.html$ /product/$1/
```

Edit: Just realised this won't work because you have product URLs that are identical in structure to product category URLs.